# Stripe Billing or using a queue

Tags: rabbitmq, stripe-payments

I have a general architecture question. I am currently designing a solution where payments need to be processed at a later date and time (asynchronously) using Stripe.

In this scenario what are the general best practices to follow. Should I be using a queue broker like RabbitMQ / Kafka which then transmits regular Stripe Payments at the specified time and date or just use the Stripe Billing / Plans / Subscription API to build the solution.

In the case of regular card payment using Stripe I don't want to store the card details on my system so am assuming I would just store the payment intent until I need to create a charge.

Any help and feedback is appreciated.

Comment: If the payments are on a recurring and regular basis, Stripe Billing it likely your best choice. If you just need to collect payment method details up front and then charge once or irregularly at later dates, I'd suggest [these docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse).

Comment: Would you say that 'later payments' in the link that you sent is the right choice for 15-30 later adhoc payments. E.g. customer creates a payment schedule (this does not have to be monthly, but can be every few days (does not have to be regular either but can be if customer chooses)

Comment: Saving a card for later payments would work for what you're describing. You'd set up your own system to make calls to create payments via Stripe's API whenever you want to actually charge. You can use Stripe Billing as well, if you prefer to set up everything at once and let Stripe handle the payment scheduling. That would be a use of [Subscription Schedules](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases) if you need to customize how much time is between any two payments.

Comment: Thanks, just ran a proof of concept using CURL and Stripe and it works fine using phases.